# How to write a post route with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am attempting to create an object by passing it three parameters via a button click, but I can't get the routing to work. The three parameters are being passed by clicking a button on the view. Here is the code for my button:

```
 <%= button_to "Create Object!", object_path(@email, @name, @size), method: :post %>
```

I am attempting to use the generic POST route to create a new object.

What needs to be adjusted? Do I need to write a custom route?

Comment: What error do you get with the code you have tried?

Comment: No route matches [POST] "/object.example@email.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass it via key value pair as shown here.

```
 <%= button_to "Create Object!", object_path(email: @email, name: @name, size: @size), method: :post %>
```

After this you can get those values via params in controller.